# Xcode 8 throwing error: App Installation Failed, NO Code Signature found

Tags: xcode8

First of all, I know this will be a duplicate answer, however I don't get any solution for this, So I am putting this.

I have update OSX to 10.12.5 and xcode to 8.3.2. Previous these were: 10.12 and 8.2.1.

In old version, my app was working fine, installing in device. After I update my system and when I was try to run the app in device it giving me error: `App Installation Failed, No Code Signature found.`
All my certificates, provisioning profiles and credentials are up to date. Still I am getting this error. I searched all the possibilities, but solution found. Any suggestions...